# How to use (double) pointer to update value of other pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I am trying to merge an array of individually sorted linked lists together to one sorted linked list (this is [Leetcode problem 23](https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-k-sorted-lists/), BTW). The linked list is defined as:

```cpp
struct ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode *next;
    ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
    ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
    ListNode(int x, ListNode *next) : val(x), next(next) {}
};
```

And my function look like this:

```cpp
ListNode* mergeKLists(vector<ListNode*> &lists) {
    ListNode *head = new ListNode(-1);
    ListNode *current = head;

    while (find_if(lists.begin(), lists.end(), [](ListNode *node) { return node; }) != lists.end()) {
        ListNode **pSmallest = nullptr;

        // find smallest node value
        for (int i = 0; i < lists.size(); i++) {
            ListNode *plist = lists.at(i);
            if (!plist) continue;
            if (!pSmallest) {
                pSmallest = new ListNode*;
                *pSmallest = plist;
            }
            else if (plist->val < (*pSmallest)->val) *pSmallest = plist;
        }

        // append smallest node to merged list
        current->next = *pSmallest;
        current = current->next;

        // advance in list with smallest node
        *pSmallest = (*pSmallest)->next;
        // ^^^^^^^^ this line does not do what I would expect
    }

    return head->next;
}
```

At the end of the function, I want to advance in the linked list with the smallest element. However, my code changes the pointer value `*pSmallest` only, without affecting the node of the linked list `pSmallest` is pointing to. How can I advance in the linked list `pSmallest` is pointing to?

I tried using references like this:

```cpp
    // ...
    // find smallest node value
    for (int i = 0; i < lists.size(); i++) {
        ListNode *plist = lists.at(i);
        if (!plist) continue;
        if (!pSmallest) {
            pSmallest = &plist;
        }
        else if (plist->val < (*pSmallest)->val) pSmallest = &plist;
    }
    // ...
```

While this does bind the value of the smallest node in the input lists to `pSmallest` and, as such, update the corresponding node in the input linked list, it also changes its value the next loop iteration, where I'm trying to re-initialize `pSmallest` to the next smallest node in the input lists.

Comment: The reference approach does not work because `plist` is declared inside the `for` and you are taking its address... that's just a random stack address, not what you want. `*pSmallest = ...` is also undefined behavior because `plist` is already out of scope by the time you try to update it.

Comment: Does leetcode let you use STL containers?

Comment: When you asked this question on the Leetcode forums, what answers did you get?

Comment: Just use `std::list` forr doubly-linked, or `std::forward_list` for singly-linked lists. Both of them have a `merge` method that can be passed to `std::ranges::fold_left` or `std::accumulate`. The answer is a one-liner in C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By assigning to `*pSmallest`, you're not updating the entry in `lists`, and in your second attempt, `&plist` is an address that is not related to `lists` either, but is an address on the stack, during one loop's iteration. So that is not right either.

You could just remember the index `i` in the list where you found the least value, and use that to update the entry in `lists`:

```
ListNode* mergeKLists(vector<ListNode*> &lists) {
    ListNode *head = new ListNode(-1);
    ListNode *current = head;

    while (true) {
        int iSmallest = -1;

        // find smallest node value
        for (int i = 0; i < lists.size(); i++) {
            if (lists[i] && (iSmallest < 0 || lists[i]->val < lists[iSmallest]->val)) {
                iSmallest = i;
            }
        }
        if (iSmallest < 0) break; // All done
        // append smallest node to merged list
        current = current->next = lists[iSmallest];
        // Remove it from the list we took it from 
        lists[iSmallest] = lists[iSmallest]->next;
    }

    return head->next;
}
```

Note that this is not an efficient solution. The number of entries in `lists` could be large, and then it is a pity to have to iterate all of them to find the least value among them... over and over again.

To improve on this, there are several approaches, such as divide-and-conquer (merging 2 lists at a time) or the use of a priority queue (heap).